# iOS Core Data: How do I add subsequent records to the 'many' of 1:many relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-location

I am writing an GPS running app that I want to store multiple locations per 'Path' or run.
I am having a little trouble understanding the new concepts of ORM style DBs. 
(I know Core Data uses SQLLite as the underlying mechanism and isn't a true ORM, but that aside..,)
I have two entities setup, 'Path' and 'Location', with a 'To-Many' relationship going from Path>>Location with Cascade Deletion, and an inverse that just has nullify for Delete.

[image]
[image]

I am doing:

```
//SEND TO CORE DATA
        bdAppDelegate *appDelegate =
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context =
        [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        // get GPS lat/lng
        double lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        double lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        // insert Path
        Path *currentPathInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Path" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        currentPathInfo.name = currentPathName;
        currentPathInfo.createddate =[NSDate date];

        // insert location/GPS point
        Location *currentPathLocation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        currentPathLocation.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat];
        currentPathLocation.lng = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lng];

        // insert 'Location' relationship to 'Path'
        [currentPathInfo addLocationsObject:currentPathLocation];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

This is on initial startup (button press)
but then how do I continue to add more 'Locations' that relate to the initial 'Path' without continuing to add more 'Path's as a result of repeating the above code?

In SQL, I'd have a PathID integer (identity) that I'd use for a foreign key in a 'Locations' table to insert locations... I'm having a disconnect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wasn't understanding was this:
I need to do a FetchRequest to check if the Path exists like so,

```
- (NSArray *)checkIfPathExistsByName {
// check first if this path exists ..
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Path" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

// Set WHERE clause
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(name LIKE %@)", currentPathName];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

// sort
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
return array;
```

}I call this in the locationManager delegate

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

// check first if this path exists ..
NSArray *array;
array = [self checkIfPathExistsByName];

if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
else
{
    if (array.count == 0){
        // if exists, just add Locations
        [self startNewPathAndInsertFirstCoordinate:newLocation forPathName:currentPathName];
    }else{            
        // start new if doesn't exist
        Path *myPath = [array lastObject];
        [self insertNewCoordinate:newLocation forPath:myPath];
    }
}
```

}
here, if it's a new path, I pass the currentPathName & location to startNewPathAndInsertFirstCoordinate, but then if it did find the Path (array.count>0) pluck the Path from the array and pass it to a different method called InsertNewCoordinate. In insertNewCoordinate since I've fetched the Path, I can set the location's relationship to it on insert, like so:

```
- (void)insertNewCoordinate:(CLLocation *)newLocation forPath:(Path *)currentPath{

//SEND TO CORE DATA    
NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"howRecent: %f\n",howRecent);    

// get GPS lat/lng
double lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

// insert location/GPS point
Location *currentPathLocation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
currentPathLocation.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat];
currentPathLocation.lng = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lng];

// insert 'Location' relationship to 'Path'
[currentPath addLocationObject:currentPathLocation];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}}
```

- (void)startNewPathAndInsertFirstCoordinate:(CLLocation *)newLocation forPathName:(NSString *)pathName{

```
NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"howRecent: %f\n",howRecent);

if (abs(howRecent) < 35.0)
{
    //Location timestamp is within the last 15.0 seconds, let's use it!
    NSLog(@"horizontalAccuracy: %f\n",newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);
    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 85.0){
        //Location seems pretty accurate, let's use it!
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
              newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
              newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"Horizontal Accuracy:%f", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);

        //SEND TO CORE DATA

        // get GPS lat/lng
        double lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        double lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        // insert Path
        Path *currentPathInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Path" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        currentPathInfo.name = currentPathName;
        currentPathInfo.createdDate =[NSDate date];

        // insert location/GPS point
        Location *currentPathLocation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        currentPathLocation.lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat];
        currentPathLocation.lng = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lng];

        // insert 'Location' relationship to 'Path'
        [currentPathInfo addLocationObject:currentPathLocation];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to create the relationship:

```
[currentPathInfo addLocationsObject:currentPathLocation];
```

or

```
currentPathLocation.path = currentPathInfo;
```

so either you need to remember your "currentPathInfo" using an ivar somewhere or fetch it from core data each time based on some kind of unique identifier (if you have one).